# Trying to get region of stability of RADUA IIA

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, implicit-differentiation, runge-kutta-methods

The method can be turned from its Butcher table into this set of explicit expressions:

$$k_1 = f\bigg(t_n + \frac{1}{3}h, y_n + \frac{5}{12}hk_1 + \frac{-1}{12}hk_2\bigg)$$
$$k_2 = f\bigg(t_n + h, y_n + \frac{3}{4}hk_1 + \frac{1}{4}hk_2\bigg)$$

$$y_{n+1} = y_n + h\frac{3}{4}k_1 + h\frac{1}{4}k_2$$

This is not enough to find the region of stability, so we pick the test function $y' = \lambda y$ and apply the method to it. Shutting your brain down and doing mindless symbol substitution yields:

$$k_1 = \lambda(y_n + \frac{5}{12}hk_1 + \frac{-1}{12}hk_2)$$
$$k_2 = \lambda(y_n + \frac{3}{4}hk_1 + \frac{1}{4}hk_2)$$

$$k_1 = f\bigg(t_n + \frac{1}{3}h, y_n + \frac{5}{12}hk_1 + \frac{-1}{12}hk_2\bigg)$$
$$k_2 = f\bigg(t_n + h, y_n +\frac{3}{4}k_1 + \frac{1}{4}k_2\bigg)$$

$$y_{n+1} = y_n + h\frac{3}{4}k_1 + h\frac{1}{4}k_2$$

Applying this to the test function $y'=\lambda y$ yields:

$$k_1 = \lambda(y_n + \frac{5}{12}hk_1 + \frac{-1}{12}hk_2)$$
$$k_2 = \lambda(y_n + \frac{3}{4}hk_1 + \frac{1}{4}hk_2)$$

So:

$$k_1 = \frac{- 2 \lambda^{2} y_{n} + 6 \lambda y_{n}}{\lambda^{2} h - 4 \lambda h + 6 h}, \  k_2 = \frac{2 \lambda^{2} y_{n} + 6 \lambda y_{n}}{\lambda^{2} h - 4 \lambda h + 6 h}$$

This then yields:

$$y_{n+1} = y_n + h\frac{3}{4}\frac{- 2 \lambda^{2} + 6 \lambda}{\lambda^{2} h - 4 \lambda h + 6 h}y_{n} + h\frac{1}{4}\frac{2 \lambda^{2} + 6 \lambda}{\lambda^{2} h - 4 \lambda h + 6 h}y_{n}$$

So:

$$y_{n+1} = y_n\bigg( 1 + \frac{3}{4}\frac{- 2 \lambda^{2} + 6 \lambda}{\lambda^{2} - 4 \lambda + 6} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{2 \lambda^{2} + 6 \lambda}{\lambda^{2} - 4 \lambda + 6}\bigg)$$

Simplifying the above through sympy gives:

$$y_{n+1} = \frac{2 \left(\lambda + 3\right)}{\lambda^{2} - 4 \lambda + 6}y_{n}$$

We can rewrite the factor by substituting $\lambda$ with $z$ as:

$$R(z) = \frac{2z + 3}{z^2 - 4z + 6}$$

And we are now interested in $|R(z)| \leq 1$.

Solving the fully expanded resulting expression is proving time consuming and sympy is also struggling at finding an explicit expression. I am not sure if a mistake was made. What should I do to get an explicit representation of the region of stability?

Comment: You got a linear system for $k_1,k_2$ in the first two equations. The solution of that you can insert into the third equation and get the approximation of the exponential solution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you for the help, I did solve the linear system and simplified as mucha s possible but I am stuck trying to get $R(z) < 1$

Comment: You did not keep up with all the factors $h$, but the result for $R(z)$ should still be correct, if you correct the distribution of $2$ in the numerator. And yes, it is now rather hard to simplify the stability condition further. Usual procedure is to get plots constructed using numerical methods, contour following, marching boxes, etc.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see, do you know of a simple to use tool I could use to give it the analytic formulation of the inqueality and see a plot of the region of stability?

Comment: I do not know the particulars but desmos has developed into a decent online graphing tool. Wolfram alpha should also be amenable as a tool to produce contour plots. Indeed any (pseudo-) CAS is able to produce contour plots, one would have to read the documentation and examples on how to steer the contour selection so that level 1 (and levels $<1$) is highlighted among the level curves around it.